# Why is route name not changing in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, screen, react-navigation-v6

I have a few screens set up like below

```
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName   = 'main'
            headerLayoutPreset = 'center'
            screenOptions      = { defaultOptions }
        >
            <Stack.Screen name = 'main' component = {Main} />
            <Stack.Screen name = 'settings' component = {Settings} />
            <Stack.Screen name = 'items' component = {Items} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Now from the Main component I have a button that takes me to the Settings screen and is set up like this.

```
    handleClick () {
        return this.props.navigation.navigate ('settings');
    }
```

Now within the `Main` component inside my `ComponentDidUpdate` I have a listener where I wanna do something based on what screen I'm on which I'm checking like this.

```
        const { route } = this.props;
        if (route.name === 'settings') {
                // Do something
        }
```

But I've noticed that when I'm on the `Settings` screen and the listener is triggered the route name is still `main`. Why is that and how do I actually check what screen I'm on?